# Duration of random position libgdx

Tags: libgdx, duration

I'm trying to make a game with libgdx but a have a problem. I have searched very well but I can't find the solution.

I try to make it last the positioning of the character of random position an Array `<Rectangle>` to each "render" it is necessary that the character have a random position of the array.

The problem is that the position of the character does not last, 
I want what lasts one second each has "render". 
I tried to make a Animation but its not working for random position.
 by cons if I defines the position (100, 100) for example it works each character image remains 1 second.

I don't know if you understood me, but what I want is the character stay 1 second at each position of the array (random position).

This my code:

```
public class MainScreen implements Screen {

SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture carte;
private Texture mario;
private Array<Rectangle>foret;
private Animation animation;
private float time;
private Rectangle mari;
private Vector2 position;
private Rectangle mickey ; 
Game game;
public MainScreen(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    carte = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("foret.png"));

    animation = new Animation(3/3f , new TextureRegion(new Texture("mario1.png")) , new TextureRegion(new Texture("mario2.png")) , new TextureRegion(new Texture("mario3.png")));

    foret = new Array<Rectangle>();

}


public void carte(){
    foret = new Array<Rectangle>();
    for(int i =0 ; i<7 ; i++){
        for(int j =0 ; j<7 ; j++){
            Rectangle fore = new Rectangle();
            fore.x = (i*100)+100;
            fore.y = (j*50)+20 ;
            fore.width = 64;
            fore.height = 64;
            foret.add(fore);
            batch.draw(carte ,fore.x , fore.y , 64 , 64 );
        }
    }
}
public Rectangle depMarioRandom(){
    foret = new Array<Rectangle>();
    for(int i =0 ; i<7 ; i++){
        for(int j =0 ; j<7 ; j++){
            Rectangle fore = new Rectangle();
            fore.x = (i*100)+100;
            fore.y = (j*50)+20 ;
            fore.width = 64;
            fore.height = 64;
            foret.add(fore);
        }}
    int random = (int) ( Math.random() * foret.size );
    Rectangle randomX = foret.get(random);
     return randomX;

}

@Override
public void show() {


}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    this.mari = depMario();
    time += delta;
    Vector2 position = new Vector2(this.mari.x, this.mari.y);

      // i try te do a copy and scaling whith time but it doesn't work

    position.cpy().scl(time);

    batch.begin();
    carte();

    batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(time), position.x, position.y, 64, 64);
    animation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);


    batch.end();
}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}
@Override
public void pause() {
}
@Override
public void resume() {
}
@Override
public void hide() {
}
@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have read your problem several time this what i understand

you want for your caractere to have a rondom poistion for a duration of one second, you could do that like this

```
 counterTime += Gdx.graphic.getDeltaTime();
        time += delta;
        if(counterTime > 1 ) {// each second ==> one call to position random
            // putting the random position here
            position = new Vector2(this.mari.x, this.mari.y);
            counterTime = 0; // reset to 0;
        }

    // do not scall anything


    batch.begin();
    carte();
```

if anything else leave a comment

good luck

Edit :

but you need just to initialize the position at the first time inside **create()** method

Comment: fist thank for your answer but is not what i'm looking for  i want my charactar stay in the position 1seconde whitout moving !!i'm not sure if you understand mee

Comment: salamoalikoum Mr Netero السلام عليكم أستاد نيتيرو انا مغريبي و لاست جيدا بي الينجليزي كل ما اواد هوووا ان يابق ماريو في ماكان لي مودت 1تانية توما يانتاكيل إلى ماكان أخر وا يابكا لنافس ال مودا   و أود أن أعتدر على هذا الخط

Comment: je sais pas si vous comprenez le francais . voila mon probléme::: je veux que le personnage se deplace aléatoirment (random) sur le tableau et a chaque position il faut qu'il reste ( le personnege) 1seconde et apres il se deplace a une autre position et qu'il reste aussi 1 seconde et ainsi de suite pour ca j fait une animation mais ca marche pas pour les position random !!! si vous voulez bien Mr netero je crois que vous etes arabe moi aussi j'en suis un si vous voullez bien m'aider j'en serait reconnaissant

Comment: سلام عليكم  i edit my my answer, try it this way (i speek in english so other could benefit from answer), tell me if it works, good luck, أخوك من الجزائر

Comment: hi, check this time i edit again, the solution that i provide is to set a counter, and after one second put your random position of mario and then set counter to ZERO so the radom position will be called once every one second, just you need to initialize the position the first time in create() method OR just initialize the counterTime to value > 1

Comment: I tried what you said but its not working as appearing character does 1/3 seconds and disappears and it does not move he makes as appearing one second and disappears after one second .....

Comment: i delete reset counterTime=0; and its work but the character doesnt move he's stiling in the same plase and he's animate what i can do to changing his place!!! and I am ashamed to tell that:: i'm new in libgdx and coding please have a big heart and help me

Comment: i think you should check your function mari.x , mari,y cause try if you try to make log : Gdx.app.log(x= ""+mari.x,"y = "+mari.y); you will notice that this log will be appeared once every one second, don't remove the conter time

Comment: no your answers is work but i don't have a controlle of the duration he appear and desepear every seconde

Comment: what is the size of your screen width and heigth , please put the log code line and show me what are you seeing : Gdx.app.log("counter ="+counterTime+"x= "+mari.x,"y = "+mari.y);

Comment: hi, i have seen your new post just remove the batch.draw() from the if  condition and the charater will not disapear

Comment: width = 800; height =480 !!!!!!!!! for the log that's what im seeing::700.0:   y = 320.0
700.0:   y = 320.0
700.0:   y = 320.0
700.0:   y = 320.0
700.0:   y = 320.0
700.0:   y = 320.0
700.0:   y = 320.0
700.0:   y = 320.0

Comment: it's work perfectly thank!!but can i ask u how i shoud make for changing position of mario

Comment: how would you like to change the position of mario using input ?! if the question is resolved don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: pleas forgive me   but i don't now where i shoud click for incereece your reputation!!please tell me how and thanks for spending u'r time

Comment: don't worry about that , my pleasure you can't upgrade my answer because you don't have enough reputation but you can accept the answer by clicking on icon accept here is link that explain more http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Good evening Mr netero i post a question and nobody has gived to mee ana answer so please if u have a time think about have a look ::this is the link:::::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749056/move-a-character-randomly-with-time