# Move a character randomly with time

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to do a game with libgdx like "Cache-cache game"

I want for my character to stay 2 seconds in the first place and to give each 2 seconds a new Random place, i.e a new element of the array `carte`.

First, I have generate my random index and the character stay in the first place.

My problem is :
 How should I make that each keyboard input makes my character move in a  random place in the array?

This is my code:

hi everybody i'm trying to do a game with libgdx like "Cache-cache game"
i want for my character staying 2 second in the first place and to give each 2seconde a new Random place of the array("carte")
*first i have generate my random index and the character stay in the first place . but my problem is ::
 how i should making for than  each keybord input my character moving in a random place in the array

any idea!!!
this is my code:::

public class MainScreen implements Screen {

```
SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture carte;
private Texture mario;
private Array<Rectangle>foret;
private Animation animation;
private float time;
private Rectangle mari;
private Vector2 position;
private Rectangle mickey ;
private float counterTime; 
Game game;
public MainScreen(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    carte = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("foret.png"));

    animation = new Animation(3/3f , new TextureRegion(new Texture("mario1.png")) , new TextureRegion(new Texture("mario2.png")) , new TextureRegion(new Texture("mario3.png")));

    foret = new Array<Rectangle>();


      this.mari = depMarioRandom();
      Vector2 position = new Vector2();
      position.x = 0;
      position.y = 0;
}


public void carte(){
    foret = new Array<Rectangle>();
    for(int i =0 ; i<7 ; i++){
        for(int j =0 ; j<7 ; j++){
            Rectangle fore = new Rectangle();
            fore.x = (i*100)+100;
            fore.y = (j*50)+20 ;
            fore.width = 64;
            fore.height = 64;
            foret.add(fore);
            batch.draw(carte ,fore.x , fore.y , 64 , 64 );
        }
    }
}
public Rectangle depMarioRandom(){
    foret = new Array<Rectangle>();
    for(int i =0 ; i<7 ; i++){
        for(int j =0 ; j<7 ; j++){
            Rectangle fore = new Rectangle();
            fore.x = (i*100)+100;
            fore.y = (j*50)+20 ;
            fore.width = 64;
            fore.height = 64;
            foret.add(fore);
        }}
    int random = (int) ( Math.random() * foret.size );
    Rectangle randomX = foret.get(random);
     return randomX;

}

@Override
public void show() {


}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    carte();
    counterTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    time += delta;
    if(counterTime > 2f ) {// each second ==> one call to position random

         position = new Vector2(mari.x, mari.y);
         counterTime =0f;


   }else { // between 2 seconds
       if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.B)) { // if "B" of Keyboard is pressed
           counterTime =3f; // go directly to the next random position

}
```

}
        batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(time), mari.x, mari.y, 64, 64);

```
    animation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);


    batch.end();
}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}
@Override
public void pause() {
}
@Override
public void resume() {
}
@Override
public void hide() {
}
@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

Comment: Do you want your character to move on a Time Event or on a keyboard event?

Comment: if  the keyboard event is hapening between 2second so the character move to another random place!!!

Comment: To be clear:  should the character move: (**A**)if two keyboard inputs are sent within less than 2s ; (**B**) Every 2s excepted if there is a user input; (**C**)if a keyboard event is sent during a 2s interval started by something that is **not** a previous keyboard event ?

Comment: to be clear ::t o move the character it must the keyboard event are sent between 2second

Comment: if u have an idea please help

Comment: If someone take time to edit your post, please don't just copy/paste your previous post over. If there was some edition, that probably means your post was bad formatted or contained lots of mistakes or wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, you want to keep the the random changes of the position by time and also add a change by keyboard inpput , right?!

try this :

```
counterTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
time += delta;
if(counterTime > 2f ) {// each second ==> one call to position random

    position = new Vector2(this.mari.x, this.mari.y);
    counterTime =0f;


}else { // between 2 seconds
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.B)) { // if "B" of Keyboard is pressed
        counterTime =3f; // go directly to the next random position

    }
}
```

Comment: first thank for spending u r time and is not working the eclipse sent me an exeption of "nullpinterexeption" of "position = new new Vector2(this.mari.x, this.mari.y); i have initialized in the create methode

Comment: i forgot the window is opening but after 2 second he send me the "exeption" i realy don't now what to do!!

Comment: and if i reset the counterTime to 0 mario doesn't have the duration of 2sec .mario apear and desepear for all of position

Comment: could you post the null pointer exception message ? , the reset is only active when you click on  "B" key

Comment: and if i delete the " this" front mari its work and no exeption is generete but the character doesn't have a duration of 2sec!!!

Comment: even i click on B nothink has changed "mario doesn't have a duration"!!but mario change the place with a big speed

Comment: this is the exeption:::: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at screen.MainScreen.render(MainScreen.java:115)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:218)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:123)

Comment: i fell ashamed to tell that but i don't have another solution ::can u try my code in your eclipse and tell me the solution if that it was possible i wille be very grateful

Comment: did you try the edited answer (refresh the answer) and remove the last position = new Vector2(this.mari.x, this.mari.y); before the batch.draw and initialise position = new Vector2(0, 0);

Comment: u see the mistake maybe

Comment: thank u Mr Netero i find the solution:::i had not ntitialize the position in the create methode

Comment: yes :) i asked you to do it in one of my comments :) good luck, just continue learning libgdx is great i made some awsome games using that library

Comment: thanks Mr netero for all u'r help and i'm curious to see you game in playStor so can you give to me the name of them

Comment: i see it thank and im i have a problem how can i get the previous score

Comment: hi, ohh i may have some bugs, thx for try it , don't forget to leave comment, the bug gonna be fixed soon, good luck

Comment: hi Mr netero i need your help !!! please this is the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020743/how-to-implement-input-two-fingers-libgdx

Comment: i joe , sorry i was really busy i write to you a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285343/how-to-detect-touching-releasing-two-objects-with-two-pointers/36285375#36285375

Comment: thank you netero but i have find the solution and thanks again for westing your time for the purpose