# How to detect touching/releasing two objects with two pointers

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to touch two rectangle at the same time using two fingers. How can i implements that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I find a solution to this problem :

```
public void detectTwoRectangleTouching() {

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched(0)){
             int x = Gdx.input.getX(0);
             int y = Gdx.input.getY(0);

             if(rectangle1.contain(x,y))
                 isRectangle1Touched = true;
             else
                 isRectangle1Touched = false;


             if(rectangle2.contain(x,y))
                 isRectangle2Touched = true;
             else
                 isRectangle2Touched = false;

        }else {
             isRectangle1Touched = false;
             isRectangle2Touched = false;

        }

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched(1)){
            int x = Gdx.input.getX(1);
            int y = Gdx.input.getY(1);

            if(rectangle1.contain(x,y))
                isRectangle1Touched = true;

            if(rectangle2.contain(x,y))
                isRectangle2Touched = true;

        }

        if(isRectangle1Touched && isRectangle2Touched) {
            // the two rectangle are pressed !!!
        }

        if(!isRectangle1Touched && !isRectangle2Touched) {
            // the two rectangle are released !!!
        }
    }
```

Comment: This a good answer for StackOverflow to have for other users to be able to find.  Thanks for posting your solution.